# Alternativa para recuperar senha ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Por padrão as senhas são recuperadas por meio de envio de e-mail. 
Eu serei o responsável para visualizar as senhas e entregá-las aos usuários caso eles esqueçam.
Não posso usar de e-mails para redefinir porque os usuários se identificam por meio da matrícula, ou seja, no banco de dados não tem endereços de e-mail para cada usuário.
Então, eu como administrador, preciso programar para que eu possa visualizar a senha, e depois informar ao usuário que solicitou.

Comment: Como você garantiria que o usuário que está tentando recuperar a senha é o dono da mesma? O intuito do e-mail ou sms é justamente esse.
A pergunta está fora do escopo porque não é realmente uma dúvida relacionada à programação. Você basicamente quer uma ideia para o seu sistema.

Answer (score 2):

**Respondendo sua pergunta:** dependendo de como é armazenada a senha é possível, **mas inseguro e nem um pouco aconselhável**.

Para que isso seja possível você precisaria que:

1. Sua senha seja armazenada sem criptografia no banco de dados
2. Um suposto "admin" deve ter uma forma de consultar os usuários e conseguir ver a senha.

Os dois itens acima devem ser **inconcebíveis** em qualquer sistema.

**Como alternativa oque pode ser sugerido:**

1. Utilizar perguntas secretas para liberar a redefinição da senha.
2. Utilizar dados pessoais para recuperação de senha (documentos pessoais, data de nascimento, sexo, nome de familiares) ou até uma combinação deles.
3. E um cenário que já vi bastante em sistemas corporativos antigos: administrador(es) que possui(em) acesso para redefinir a senha da pessoa se a mesma se identificar. Dentro de uma corporação isso até é possível já que você facilmente consegue identificar uma pessoa por usa matrícula e outros recursos internos.

Os 3 itens acima ainda não são aconselháveis, mas não são tão ruins quanto ter acesso a senha. Note que todas opções devem sempre ser para redefinir a senha e nunca consultar. Mesmo quem tiver acesso ao banco de dados do sistema não deve saber qual a senha dos usuários.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas. Eu já busquei na internet uma maneira de usar de perguntas para redefinir senhas mas não encontrei. Não sei como escrever o código. Se você puder ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: @DPWSReceptivo, acho que nesse caso se trataria de outra dúvida. Você precisaria abrir uma nova pergunta com oque você já tentou fazer, detalhes de como está armazenando seu usuário, como está disponibilizando as perguntas, como ele escolhe as respostas e em qual dessas partes está com problema.